# Adding CompositeTemplateId Causes Error

Tags: docusignapi

Adding a `compositeTemplateId`, as in the following JSON, causes the following error:

```
{
  errorCode: "ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE"
  message: "The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line."
}
```

Removing the `compositeTemplateId` prevents the error, but I need the composite template id for other reasons.

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please Print, Complete and Sign Document",
    "emailBlurb": "Please print and complete documents and sign on paper. ",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",        
            "customFields": {
                "textCustomFields": [{
                    "name": "MyOwnField",
                    "required": "true",
                    "show": "true",
                    "value": "MyValue"
                }]
            },
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "requireSignOnPaper": "true",
                    "name": "Millard Fillmore",
                    "email": "dgilbert@firstallied.com",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "routingOrder": "1"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Corestone Account Application.pdf",
            "transformPdfFields": false
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm), if you specify a **compositeTemplateId** value in the JSON part of the API request, then the "**Content-Disposition**" value of the corresponding document part within the request must also specify that same value for **compositeTemplateId**.

If you specify **compositeTemplateId** within the JSON part of the request, but do ***NOT*** specify **compositeTemplateId** in the **Content-Disposition** of the corresponding document part within the request, you'll get an error message indicating that the Envelope is incomplete -- because DocuSign cannot locate the document part utilizing the **compositeTemplateId** value that's specified in the JSON. So, I'd suspect that your issue is being caused by the fact that you're not currently specifying the **compositeTemplateId** value within the **Content-Disposition** of the document part in the request.

The following request shows an example of a multi-part "Create Envelope" API request that specifies the same **compositeTemplateId** value in both:

- the **inlineTemplate** object (within the JSON part of the message)

AND

- the **Content-Disposition** value (within the document part of the message)

***Example request***

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/201105/envelopes HTTP/1.1

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"johnDoe@gmail.com","Password":"johnsPassword!","IntegratorKey":"ABCD-eae5f282-j4k3-47c3-b293-1c4cf55b-93gh"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
    "emailSubject": "Test Email Subject",
    "status" : "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "compositeTemplateId": 1,
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "customFields": {
                "textCustomFields": [
                    {
                        "value": "1234567",
                        "required": "false",
                        "show": "true",
                        "name": "ProductId"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "sallysEmail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Sally Adamson",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "defaultRecipient": "true",
                    "emailNotification": {
                                "emailSubject": "Recipient specific subject",
                                "emailBody": "Recipient specific body"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": 1,
            "name": "NDA",
            "transformPdfFields": "true"
        }
    }]
}
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="SampleForm.pdf"; compositeTemplateId="1"; documentid="1"

...pdf_byte_stream_here...

--MY_BOUNDARY--
```